# Регулярное выражение(только цифры и запятые)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Помогите, пожалуйста, составить регулярное выражение, чтобы если $a не соответствовало "n,n,n,n,", то выводилось 1.

В данном случае, моё регулярное выражение будет верным, даже если $a = 1,5,b,d,e. А нужно именно чтобы были только цифры.

```
$a = '1,5,';

if(!preg_match('/([0-9]+)\,/i', $a)) {
 echo 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$a = '1,5,';
if(!preg_match('/^(?:\d\,)+$/', $a)) {
 echo 1;
}
```

^ - начало строки

$ - конец строки

(?:\d\,) - цифра и запятая

+ - ищем один или более раз (в данном случае цифру с запятой)

Если нужно искать без запятой в конце:

```
/^(?:\d\,)+\d?$/
```

Если через запятую будут указаны большие числа (132,564,234324):

```
/^(?:\d+\,)+\d?$/
```

либо как предложил [[@Palmervan](/users/3526/palmervan)](/users/3526/palmervan):

```
/^(?:\d\,?)+$/
```

Comment: `/^(?:\d\,?)+$/` после цифры запятой может и небыть.

Comment: Из условия задачи этого не видно.
Приведенные примеры: 'n,n,n,n,' и '1,5,'

Comment: То что Вы написали будет соответствовать даже такому: 1234,3425,3,4
Можно так: /^(?:\d\,?)+\d?$/